# $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$. Prove that $\frac{1}{f'(x_1)} + \frac{1}{f'(x_2)} = 2$ for some $x_1, x_2 \in [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus

> Given smooth real-valued function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ prove that there exist $x_1, x_2 \in [0, 1], x_1 \ne x_2$ such that  $\frac{1}{f'(x_1)} + \frac{1}{f'(x_2)} = 2$.

The only thing I could think of is noticing that by Lagrange's Mean Value theorem there exists $x'$ with $f'(x') = 1$:
$$f(1) - f(0) = f(x')(1 - 0)$$

I can neither prove there exists another point with derivative being equal to $1$ not come up with another solution idea. Could you help me please?

Comment: Not sure if it provides any additional insight, but you are trying to prove that $\exist x_1, x_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_1), f(x_2)$ have harmonic mean of $1$. Interesting why would this be useful? I never saw harmonic mean practically used outside of basic physics (average of two speeds for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's a smooth function, there exists a point $x_0 \in (0,1)$, where $f(x_0) = 0.5$. Now apply the mean value theorem to the two intervals, and you'll get that there exist two points on left and right side of $x_0$ respectively - $x_1$ and $x_2$, where:

$$f'(x_1) = \frac{0.5}{x_0}$$
$$f'(x_2) = \frac{0.5}{1-x_0}$$

QED

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the problem is using the intermediate value theorem for derivatives. You can show there exist $n$ distinct points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ satisfying $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{f'(x_k)} = n$ as follows:

If $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ the result is trivial. Otherwise there exists a point $x_0$ with $f(x_0) \not= x_0$.

The mean value theorem provides to points $c_1$ and $c_2$ with $f'(c_1) > 1$ and $f'(c_2) < 1$.  It follows that $f'$ attains *every* value in the interval $[f'(c_2),f'(c_1)]$ which makes the selection of the $x_k$ quite straightforward.